# Solana anchor building smart contract in Ubuntu 22.04 failing with libss.so.1.1 error

Tags: anchor-solana

I am using Anchor for my Solana smart contract.
This morning, I have updated my ubuntu to latest 22.04 LTS

> Distributor ID: Ubuntu   Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS    Release:
> 22.04    Codename:       jammy

My anchor version is 0.24.2 and smart contract build are failing with

> error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open
> shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrade the libssl from 3.x to 1.1.

> You can try this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1404383

wget http://nz2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb*

Answer (score 1):

as i can't libssl1.1_1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb ,so i tried

wget http://nz2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb && sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb

fortunately, it works